# Save file base64 in blob column

Tags: java, spring-batch, blob

I have in a variable string base 64 like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA.......
```

I need to save that in a column type blob, I need to decode the string I think and what more before saving to blob column

Comment: decode the string how? I think you can directly save it to the BLOB column.

Comment: Can I save directly the base64 in blob column? and should I save all the string data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA....... or I have to split it at ','? thanks @AbuBakarKhan

Comment: are you using spring JPA ? maybe if you share some code related to storage I can help out more

Comment: The only thing i don´t know is if for saving the blob i save all the string data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA... or i have to split it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), the URL part of the BASE64 String that is in your case `data:image/jpeg;base64`.

Assuming your using the [Standard Base64 Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) then you would need to split your string inorder to decode it to an image, as shown in the code below:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;


def sourceData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA';

// tokenize the data
def parts = sourceData.tokenize(",");
def imageString = parts[1];

// create a buffered image
BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();

// write the image to a file
File outputfile = new File("response.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
```

Thus **if you want to save information related to the file format of the image then do keep the Full Base64 String when saving to the Database Clob Column**, and when reading you can decode only the DATA PART (After the Base64 URL) to the actual image while th base64 URL can help in deciding the format of the image.

Comment: thanks so I will save the whole string in the blob column so when I read I can see which type of format is, thanks!!

Comment: your welcome, you can mark as an accepted answer/upvote if it solves your issue!

Comment: Done @AbuBakar Khan